# MySQL "Row size too large" error is triggering - when by all accounts it shouldn't be

Tags: mysql

I've got a bizarre issue with MySQL (specifically `MySQL 5.5.5-10.0.26-MariaDB`) where it is throwing the "Row size too large" error when (by my logic!) it shouldn't be.

I have an ExpressionEngine installation that was recently migrated to InnoDB from MyISAM for performance reasons. The main entry table is throwing errors when trying to update large entries:

> Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

The `UPDATE` query ExpressionEngine is trying to run is huge (updating around 50 columns, with a lot of large content). **But this error is only ever thrown when updating one specific `TEXT` column ("`field_id_13`"), with data only 1500 bytes in length.**

- If I comment out the setting of `field_id_13`, the query works every single time
- If I comment out `field_id_13` and add extra fields totalling more data being inserted, the query still works!
- It's only this one column that is causing the error - commenting or adding any other columns gives no problems at all

The column is being set with the following data:

```
`field_id_13`  = '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',
```

That's 1540 characters of data. The data for `field_id_13` is base64-encoded data of a serialised PHP object (not my design decision unfortunately - this is done by an EE field type). When decoded, the string length is only 1154 characters.

The column `field_id_13` is set as `TEXT`, though I have also tried setting it as `VARCHAR(10000)`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `LONGTEXT`, and `BLOB` - neither of which make any difference as the error is always thrown.

The MySQL installation is using the Antelope file system. I am aware a move can be made to Barracuda and I can use `ROW_FORMAT=compressed` but the client is very performance-conscious and I am reluctant to bring the increase in disk usage overhead for compressing/decompressing on the fly.

Any ideas what's going on?

For reference, here is my `CREATE TABLE` result. I'm well aware it's awful, but is generated automatically by ExpressionEngine and unfortunately I have no control over it:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp_channel_data` (
  `entry_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `channel_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_id_2` text,
  `field_ft_2` tinytext,
  `field_id_3` text,
  `field_ft_3` tinytext,
  `field_id_4` text,
  `field_ft_4` tinytext,
  `field_id_5` text,
  `field_ft_5` tinytext,
  `field_id_12` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_12` tinytext,
  `field_id_13` text,
  `field_ft_13` tinytext,
  `field_id_18` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_18` tinytext,
  `field_id_19` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_19` tinytext,
  `field_id_20` text,
  `field_ft_20` tinytext,
  `field_id_21` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_21` tinytext,
  `field_id_22` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_22` tinytext,
  `field_id_23` text,
  `field_ft_23` tinytext,
  `field_id_24` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `field_ft_24` tinytext,
  `field_id_25` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_25` tinytext,
  `field_id_26` text,
  `field_ft_26` tinytext,
  `field_id_46` float DEFAULT '0',
  `field_ft_46` tinytext,
  `field_id_47` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_47` tinytext,
  `field_id_49` text,
  `field_ft_49` tinytext,
  `field_id_50` text,
  `field_ft_50` tinytext,
  `field_id_51` text,
  `field_ft_51` tinytext,
  `field_id_52` text,
  `field_ft_52` tinytext,
  `field_id_53` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_53` tinytext,
  `field_id_54` text,
  `field_ft_54` tinytext,
  `field_id_55` text,
  `field_ft_55` tinytext,
  `field_id_56` text,
  `field_ft_56` tinytext,
  `field_id_91` text,
  `field_ft_91` tinytext,
  `field_id_92` text,
  `field_ft_92` tinytext,
  `field_id_93` text,
  `field_ft_93` tinytext,
  `field_id_94` text,
  `field_ft_94` tinytext,
  `field_id_95` text,
  `field_ft_95` tinytext,
  `field_id_96` text,
  `field_ft_96` tinytext,
  `field_id_97` text,
  `field_ft_97` tinytext,
  `field_id_98` text,
  `field_ft_98` tinytext,
  `field_id_99` text,
  `field_ft_99` tinytext,
  `field_id_100` text,
  `field_ft_100` tinytext,
  `field_id_101` text,
  `field_ft_101` tinytext,
  `field_id_102` text,
  `field_ft_102` tinytext,
  `field_id_103` text,
  `field_ft_103` tinytext,
  `field_id_104` text,
  `field_ft_104` tinytext,
  `field_id_105` text,
  `field_ft_105` tinytext,
  `field_id_106` text,
  `field_ft_106` tinytext,
  `field_id_107` mediumtext,
  `field_ft_107` tinytext,
  `field_id_109` text,
  `field_ft_109` tinytext,
  `field_id_110` text,
  `field_ft_110` tinytext,
  `field_id_111` text,
  `field_ft_111` tinytext,
  `field_id_112` text,
  `field_ft_112` tinytext,
  `field_id_115` text,
  `field_ft_115` tinytext,
  `field_id_116` text,
  `field_ft_116` tinytext,
  `field_id_119` text,
  `field_ft_119` tinytext,
  `field_id_120` text,
  `field_ft_120` tinytext,
  `field_id_121` text,
  `field_ft_121` tinytext,
  `field_id_122` text,
  `field_ft_122` tinytext,
  `field_id_123` text,
  `field_ft_123` tinytext,
  `field_id_124` text,
  `field_ft_124` tinytext,
  `field_id_125` text,
  `field_ft_125` tinytext,
  `field_id_126` text,
  `field_ft_126` tinytext,
  `field_id_146` text,
  `field_ft_146` tinytext,
  `field_id_147` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `field_ft_147` tinytext,
  `field_id_148` text,
  `field_ft_148` tinytext,
  `field_id_149` text,
  `field_ft_149` tinytext,
  `field_id_150` text,
  `field_ft_150` tinytext,
  `field_id_151` text,
  `field_ft_151` tinytext,
  `field_id_152` text,
  `field_ft_152` tinytext,
  `field_id_153` text,
  `field_ft_153` tinytext,
  `field_id_154` text,
  `field_ft_154` tinytext,
  `field_id_155` text,
  `field_ft_155` tinytext,
  `field_id_158` text,
  `field_ft_158` tinytext,
  `field_id_159` text,
  `field_ft_159` tinytext,
  `field_id_160` text,
  `field_ft_160` tinytext,
  `field_id_161` text,
  `field_ft_161` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: show your `show create table ...` result.

Comment: @spirit Done - see edit.

Comment: You might want to think about re-designing your database. This table layout is wrong.

Comment: wow... are you sure you really need that kind of a table? =)

Comment: maybe you can restructure your data, or split information among several tables?

Comment: I know it's terrible. I did not design this table, it is constructed automatically by ExpressionEngine CMS. I have no say in how it is structured, but unfortunately am stuck with this situation for a client's site. Does anyone have any further ideas? :(

Comment: Add another horrible table and link it via foreign key or something? If you really want bad ideas to continue supporting bad use of RDBMS, use that one. Of course, anyone who's not in your shoes should curse and insult me with everything possible for suggesting that and I sincerely hope even you won't use it :)